# Use VideoCapture() in two different function within same class OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm making a GUI in which one button will display the video and another button will start capturing frames from that video at certain intervals.

Here, are the functions that are called by the buttons:-

```
def capture(self):
    global img_location
    global camera

    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    return_value, image = camera.read()
    time.sleep(2)   #set the delay you want in frame
    now_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())

    img_location = './timelapse_focus/'+FolderName+'/'+ now_time +'.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite(img_location, image)
    del(camera)


def display(self):
    # Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
    # If the input is the camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name

    # Check if camera opened successfully
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    if (camera.isOpened()== False): 
      print("Error opening video stream or file")

    # Read until video is completed
    while(camera.isOpened()):
      # Capture frame-by-frame
      ret, frame = camera.read()
      if ret == True:

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)

        # Press <q> on keyboard to  exit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break

      # Break the loop
      else: 
        break

    # When everything done, release the video capture object
    camera.release()

    # Closes all the frames
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    for i in range (1,5):
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

It's showing the following error:-

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Bad file descriptor
Unable to stop the stream.: Bad file descriptor
```

To do the same I tried to declare the camera variable globally. 
But it's not working. Even I used `self. camera`, it is also not working. 
Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you try to open `cv2.VideoCapture(1)` both in the `display(self)` and in the `capture(self)`. Set `frame` as `self.frame` in `display(self)` and use it in `capture(self)`. Like this:

```
def capture(self):

    time.sleep(2)   #set the delay you want in frame
    now_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())

    img_location = './timelapse_focus/'+FolderName+'/'+ now_time +'.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite(img_location, self.frame)



def display(self):
    # Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
    # If the input is the camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name

    # Check if camera opened successfully
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    if (camera.isOpened()== False): 
       print("Error opening video stream or file")

    # Read until video is completed
    while(camera.isOpened()):
      # Capture frame-by-frame
      ret, self.frame = self.camera.read()
      if ret == True:

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Frame',self.frame)

        # Press <q> on keyboard to  exit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break

      # Break the loop
      else: 
    break

    # When everything done, release the video capture object
    camera.release()

    # Closes all the frames
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    for i in range (1,5):
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

This is only for capturing one frame each time you call `capture(self)`. Otherwise you need to add a while loop and the method in a Thread in order not to crash your GUI.

Comment: Now, it's showing 
AttributeError: PageOne instance has no attribute 'frame'

In the capture() function.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not able to reproduce your error. You are sure you changed `frame` to `self.frame` in `display(self)` and `image` to `self.frame` in `capture(self)` ?

Comment: Yes, I have made the changes

Comment: Do I need to change camera to self.camera too. 
As, it's showing this error now:-
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'camera' referenced before assignment

Comment: Ohh..it's working now.
Ijust removed the del(camera) and change the camera to self.camera

Comment: But it's only saving one frame at all the time intervals

Comment: Yep, you need to add a `while True` loop inside capture and run the function in a thread.